# How to send a POST from Postman using a JSON as the data?

Tags: json, post, postman

How do we send a JSON from the body in Postman to a Post Web API controller?

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string x1, string x2) {
    Debug.WriteLine("POST resource called (" + x1 + ", " + x2 + ")." );
}
```

So in Postman, for the Params section, this works:

[image]

If I added this JSON in the body and selected JSON, the resource is not found:

```
{
    "x1" : "Hello",
    "x2" : "World"
}
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear. What is the backend technology? How are you trying to send JSON in body? Does you backend have any method to accept a single JSON string from the client?

Comment: I have IIS Express running ASP.NET.  In Postman, we can go to Body > raw and select JSON where we can create our JSON string.  The only Post method I have is like the one above.  I'm not even sure how to declare the parameter so the Post() will pick up these POST requests with a JSON in the data.

Comment: Is your request URL (i. e. route) correctly mapped to this method? It must be defined in somewhere in source code.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I follow.  I get it about re-mapping a route for a GET where we could do http://localhost/a/b/c/d/newname/123, but I'd like to just keep it with the default settings for this endpoint: http://localhost/api/MyController/

Now I want my client to send a POST request using the endpoint and pass it a JSON with the data for x1 and x2.